# To aggregate a csv file having day wise data into month

Tags: r, csv, date, aggregate

I have a csv file named crime.csv as below:-

```
OFFENSE_CODE    OFFENSE_TYPE        OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION             DISTRICT    DAY YEAR    MONTH   STREET          NO_OF_CRIME
1106            Confidence Games    FRAUD - CREDIT CARD / ATM FRAUD     B2      1   2018    2       WASHINGTON ST   1
3201            Property Lost       PROPERTY - LOST                     B2      15  2018    3       ELM HILL AVE    1
1001            Counterfeiting      FORGERY / COUNTERFEITING            D4      9   2018    1       TREMONT ST      1
2629            Harassment          HARASSMENT                          E5      1   2018    1       CROWN POINT DR  1
1001            Counterfeiting      FORGERY / COUNTERFEITING            E5      8   2018    4       REDGATE RD      1
1106            Confidence Games    FRAUD - CREDIT CARD / ATM FRAUD     D4      22  2018    2       BOYLSTON ST     1
2629            Harassment          HARASSMENT                          B2      9   2017    10      AKRON ST        1
1102            Fraud               FRAUD - FALSE PRETENSE / SCHEME     A7      25  2018    4       LIVERPOOL ST    1
3201            Property Lost       PROPERTY - LOST                     D14     1   2018    1       FIDELIS WAY     1
1106            Confidence Games    FRAUD - CREDIT CARD / ATM FRAUD     E5      12  2018    4       SPRING ST       1
3201            Property Lost       PROPERTY - LOST                     A1      30  2018    4       NASHUA ST       1
```

I need to aggregate this data into monthly data based on OFFENCE_CODE. So that NO_OF_CRIMES gets aggregated for that particular month. Any help would be really great.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` is the name of the dataframe:

```
aggregate(x$NO_OF_CRIME, by = list(x$OFFENCE_CODE, x$MONTH), FUN = sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   group_by(OFFENCE_CODE, YEAR, MONTH) %>%
   mutate(SUM_NO_OF_CRIME = sum(NO_OF_CRIME))
```

Comment: This is giving the sum of all NO_OF_CRIMES. I need my csv file to be aggregated by month and stored in the same table. I need monthwise data as I need to join this table with another table based on month and year.

Comment: @supriyasingh  If you need to create a column, use `mutate`. updated